# Slickgrid How to avoid cyclic complaint on JSON.stringify(dataView.getGroups())

Tags: jquery, json, slickgrid, dataview

I would like to use JSON.stringify method to convert slickgrid groups data into text and post to server. However it doesn't work due to the JSON object is cyclic structure:

I use code as below:

```
grps=JSON.stringify(dataView.getGroups()));
```

So far any alternative way for me to capture the json result in current dataview or stringify the getGroups() object?

I manage to get dataView's item by

```
$.each(ar,function(index,value){
    db+=JSON.stringify(dataView.getItemById(value))+",";
    //db.push(dataView.getItemById(value));
    //console.log("row item: " + value+",data:"+JSON.stringify(dataView.getItemById(value)));
});
```

But it is not the result I want cause it not reflect nested group structure in json string.

thanks help

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this requirement by dump it into string using foreach and manually combine them:
Some column not needed simply ignore it.

```
function dumpgroup2json(obj,lv){
    var rs="[";
    $.each(obj,function(i,v){
        rs+="{";
        $.each(v,function(i1,v1){


        //  console.log("index: "+i+", 2ndlevel: " +i1+": "+v1);
                if(i1=="rows"){
                    if(v1)
                        rs=rs+' "rows" : ' +dumprow2json(v1) + ',';
                    }
                    else if(i1=="groups"){
                        if(v1)
                            rs=rs+' "groups_'+lv+'" : ' +dumpgroup2json(v1,(lv+1)) + ',';

                    }
                    else if (i1=="level" ||i1=="count" ||i1=="value" || i1=="title"  )
                        rs+='"'+i1+'" : "'+v1+'",';             

        });
        rs=rs.substr(0,rs.length-1)+"";

        rs+="},";
    });
        rs= rs.substr(0,rs.length-1)+"]";
    //console.log(rs);
    return rs;

}
```